# 8x8 Grid with no parallels

Tags: logical-deduction, geometry, optimization

In the 8x8 grid graph shown below;

[image]

you can put points to the edge of grid as shown below (blue dots).

[image]

The example above has 4 points and you construct a line between two points as shown below;

[image]

so the question is

> What is the maximum number of points you can have in an 8x8 grid graph, where no pairs of distinct points can create two parallel lines?

Note that one point cannot be used more than once while creating a new line and 4 points in a line is counted as parallel as well.

If this question was asked for 2x2, the answer would be 5:

[image]

Comment: Do $4$ points in a line count as two parallel lines?

Comment: @RobPratt yes :)

Comment: I don´t understand where are those 5 lines in the 2x2 grid, If I don't count the perpendicular lines I count 4 no parallel lines, if I count the perpendicular lines I count 6 no parallel lines, can you show where are those 5 lines?

Comment: @stramin  it is not the lines you need to count, it is points.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm using a $9 \times 9$ matrix, with $1$ if there is a point and $0$ otherwise.

> $11$ points:
>
> ```
> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
> 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1
> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
> 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
> 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
> 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
> 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
> 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
> ```

Comment: Let me guess - the solving method was "Integer Linear Programming" :)

Comment: @bobble I'd rather not say. :)

Comment: It seems the maximum number is $(n+2)$ for any $n\geq 3$? ($n$ is the number of points on the edge) Could you please check it?

Comment: @fljx [showed](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/116157/65277) that $n+2$ is an upper bound.  It is attained for $n\in\{3,\dots,9\}$, but I don't know about larger $n$.

Answer (score 4):

It's fairly simple to prove an upper bound of:

> 11 points

> Just look at how many points are in each row.
>
>  - If any two rows contain two (or more) points. You have two horizontal lines. So at most one row can have more than one point.
>  - If any row contains four (or more) points. You have two horizontal lines. So one row can have at most three points.
>
>  For a maximum of 8+3 = 11 points.
>
>  And @RobPratt has provided a solution with 11 points.

Answer (score -1):

### Disclaimer

I misread the question and thought it said that I have to pick the max number of lines. I'm just leaving this up here in case it helps anyone

I got to

> 37 lines

Photo:

> [image]

It may be possible to get this higher, but not by much as the upper bound is

> 40 lines cuz 81 pts/2(pts/line) = 40.5 lines

Comment: The question seems to be about placing the points, and letting an adversary draw the lines. Or at least that's how I read it.

Comment: @Bass That wasn't stated in the post.

Comment: It says "no pairs of distinct points can create two parallel lines". For example A&B and R&T in your attempt can create parallel lines.

Comment: @Bass It appears that I misread the question. Thanks for pointing this out.